# There are some English cases that, I comes with are and is instead of am

Tags: grammar

Like I mentioned in the question title: 
 
You and I are friends. (I takes are) 

 It will be great, if you mention some cases just like that. 
 
I takes "is". he takes "do" and so on. 
 What is the secret of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mis-analysing the sentence. The subject is *you and I* which is plural, and so takes *are*.

*I* on its own never takes *are* or *is*.

There is one apparent exception, though it isn't one really. In speech, tag questions are usually of the form *isn't it?*, *aren't you?*. But when the subject is *I*, most people say *aren't I?* (though a few say *amn't I?*). But this is not really an exception: it's just that the expected form *amn't* has got changed in speech to *aren't*.

Comment: In this case: I is a pronoun. it takes is.

Comment: Ah, the [use-mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction). The subject of "I is a pronoun" is not the first person prounoun: it is a word which happens to be the first person pronoun.